# Using ConcurrentLinkedQueue causes error

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, syntax-error

I'm getting following error when using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`:

> Error : local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

I have pretty simple code, I just want to add value to the queue from multiple threads. The problem is that similar code works fine with similar types of queries.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue; 

ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> concurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double>();
threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
startTime = System.nanoTime();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThread; i++) {
    Thread addingThread;
    addingThread = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int j = 0; j < targetNumber; j++) {
            concurrentLinkedQueue.add(5.55); // error line
        }
    });
    threads.add(addingThread);
}

threads.forEach(Thread::start);

for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

What is wrong here? I'm trying to add const value, how is that possible, that it says me about the value being not final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because variables declared inside a method are put on the stack (they only live for the duration of the method), and not on the heap, you can't access them from inside local anonymous inner classes declared inside that method (such as your thread) unless you declare those instances as `final`.

So you need to change the line where you declare the `concurrentLinkedQueue` to

```
final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> concurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double>();
```

This ensures that the queue is accessible to the thread you've created even if the method in which the thread is created exits before the thread finishes.

I can't see where you've declared `targetNumber`, but you'll need to ensure that it's either defined outside of the method, or it's also marked as `final`.  I'm guessing since it's not the line that's causing troubles, it's defined elsewhere.

Comment: You right about `targetNumber` - it's not final and it changes. Anyway making queue final saved from the error.